# MongoDB Install Error

Tags: mongodb, pecl, nosql

Just setup a fresh server at MediaTemple (dedicated virtual / CentOS Linux) and installed the developer tools, but Mongo won't install, any ideas?

Also, it's trying to DL version 1.2.10 I assume I can run `pecl upgrade mongo` once it is installed to go to 2.0.6 right?

Here's my output:

```
[root ~]# pecl install mongo
downloading mongo-1.2.10.tgz ...
Starting to download mongo-1.2.10.tgz (86,463 bytes)
.....................done: 86,463 bytes
36 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20041225
Zend Module Api No:      20060613
Zend Extension Api No:   220060519
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-root/mongo-1.2.10
running: /root/tmp/pear/cache/mongo-1.2.10/configure
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... //bin/sed
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... configure: error: cannot run C compiled     programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details.
ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/cache/mongo-1.2.10/configure' failed
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not installing mongodb with pecl, here you're installing the PHP driver for mongodb.

To install mongodb on CentOS, please follow these instructions [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-redhat-centos-or-fedora-linux/). These instructions show you how to add the 10gen repo, which will then enable you (using yum) to install the latest production-ready mongodb release (2.0.6).

I realise that it's not Ubuntu but egarding your issue with installing the PHP driver, does it make any difference if you run

```
sudo pecl install mongo
```

There's some information [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Language+Center) on installing the mongo php driver, just replace the 'apt-get' elements with 'yum' as the same libraries, dependencies apply afaik.

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php) on using the mongo php driver.